# WPF C# Ninject with a mainViewModel and multiple viewmodel problem

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm having problem with with implementing ninject in my application.

My application contains of a MainView view and viewmodel.
The MainView is using resource.xaml to draw the GUI. I'm also binding the viewmodel for each resource in my MainView.xaml.

I'm having a problem with implementing Ninject.

In my MainViewModel I'm creating;

```
    public logViewModel ChangelogViewModel { get; set; } = new logViewModel();
    public TabViewModel ToolTabViewModel { get; set; } = new ToolTabViewModel();
```

which I send as viewmodel content for the resource files.
How can I use ninject to automatically creating those additional viewmodels?

I'm also having problem with using the kernel to bind interfaces.
When my constructor launch, I don't get the functions from the ninject kernel binding.

It seem like at runtime when I check constructor, it only get my connectionstring which is a private variable in the viewmodel. But non of my functions is there.

```
        Bind<IDataAccessor>().To<DataAccessor>().InSingletonScope().WithConstructorArgument("connectionString", connectionString);
```

Another weird thing is that it doesn't seem like my accessor is running its function when it's called.  Does partial class have something to do with this?

I'm working with telerik components.

Answer (score 0):

Like most DI containers, Ninject works with constructor injection.
You tell it what to create when a class/viewmodel constructor asks for a specific interface.

When you Get an instance of that class it provides the parameters you registered.

A quick and dirty example for flavour.

Instead of just a starturl I'm calling startup to show mainwindow.

```
    private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        var nj = new StandardKernel();
        nj.Bind<IVMOne>().To<VMOne>().InTransientScope();

        MainWindow mw = new MainWindow();
        mw.DataContext = nj.Get<MainWindowViewModel>();
        mw.Show();
    }
```

Here I say when I ask for a IVMOne then give me a VMONe.
MainWindowViewModel wants a IVMOne for it's ctor.
So when I Get a mainwindowviewmodel ninject also gives me a VMOne.

```
class MainWindowViewModel
{
    public IVMOne VMOne { get; set; }
    public MainWindowViewModel(IVMOne vmOne)
    {
        VMOne = vmOne;
    }
}
```

Which I can then bind to:

```
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding VMOne.Hello}"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Hi friend, thanks a lot for your reply. I've did something like you did. Let's say in the dataaccess project, I manage to set WithConstructorArgument and bind it to the string variable in the constructor in the accessor in the dataaccess.

nj.Bind<IAccessor>().To<Accessor>().InTransientScope();
Then I'm trying to get this in my viewmodel, but it doesn't work. I'm only getting the private variable string connectionString, but not all my functions.

Comment: What do I do for other viewmodels? Like I kind of god partial class viewmodels, like mainview xaml sends the viewmodel through the "content" parameter, and I specifiy the resource template xaml it should use.

Comment: public MainViewModel(CategoryViewModel categoryViewModel , ICategoryAccessor categoryAccessor )
        {
            _categoryViewModel = categoryViewModel ;
            _categoryAccessor = categoryAccessor ;

When I check the CategoryAccessor, I can only find the private string which I declared as static member. My functions is not in the constructor...

Comment: You're assuming I understand exactly what categoryaccessor is and what you're expecting. And you're also asking more questions in comments. If something is expecting to have another object injected you just Bind it to define what that should be. I think you can also just have a class in ctor as well and it'll instantiate one of them when you Get.

Comment: I see now that my binding works atleast the .WithConstructorArgument("connectionString", connectionString), since I can see the string connectionString which I have in the constructor.

But I can't seem to see the rest of the functions that is in the class.

Comment: Me neither. Which makes it kind of tricky to give advice beyond making sure they're public.

Comment: They are in public both interface and in the class.

Comment: Hi again @andy, I managed to get it to work for MainWindow.xaml.